Planner server in GPS based navigation system for Nav2
I examined the GPS-based application of the Navigation 2 system found in this link in detail. After the application, I ran each step in detail. I actively observed mapViz, Map API plugins, etc. structures and tested them within the system structure.
Question:
For the system (video), in the last seconds, it does not plan the path using the relevant cost_map and does not choose the shortest path as it did at the beginning of the video. Here, it moves over the previously traveled area. How can I close this situation? I examined the Related demo in detail and did not see a structure related to this subject. I want Planner server to work in the shortest way possible. I would be glad if you could help. Thanks...
Note: 'nav2_no_map_params.yaml file'

I tested some structures related to the subject but it still doesn't work as I want. I tried all the sub-parameters of the 'obstacle_layer' parameter created by the global costmap defined according to the video and the black area is deleted but the 'inflation_layer' layer found by the globalcostmap remains dysfunctional and hits the obstacle. Planner server does not provide the output by not defining the shortest path and only finds the shortest path in the black area provided by 'obstacle_layer'. How can I fix this? I would be glad if you could help me.
